# Sending mails to outlook.office365.com using secret key through JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have a client_id and secret key for connecting to `outlook.office365.com` server. I have to send mails to the server through JMeter.

I don't see any option for providing above keys in my SMTP Sampler. How can I do this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it using [SMTP Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SMTP_Sampler), it only allows username/password authentication as of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6)

If your mailbox doesn't allow SMTP connections using username and password the only option would be going for [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Something like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHeader

import javax.mail.Session
import javax.mail.Store

public String getAuthToken(String tanantId, String clientId, String client_secret) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost loginPost = new HttpPost("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tanantId + "/oauth2/v2.0/token");
    String scopes = "https://outlook.office365.com/.default";
    String encodedBody = "client_id=" + clientId + "&scope=" + scopes + "&client_secret=" + client_secret
    +"&grant_type=client_credentials";
    loginPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(encodedBody, ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED));
    loginPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("cache-control", "no-cache"));
    CloseableHttpResponse loginResponse = client.execute(loginPost);
    InputStream inputStream = loginResponse.getEntity().getContent();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    byte[] response = IOUtils.readFully(inputStream, buffer);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JavaType type = objectMapper.constructType(
            objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(Map.class, String.class, String.class));
    Map<String, String> parsed = new ObjectMapper().readValue(response, type);
    return parsed.get("access_token");
}

Properties props = new Properties();

props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
props.put("mail.imap.host", "outlook.office365.com");
props.put("mail.imap.port", "993");
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
props.put("mail.imap.user", mailAddress);
props.put("mail.debug", "true");
props.put("mail.debug.auth", "true");

String token = getAuthToken(tanantId, clientId, client_secret);
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
session.setDebug(true);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect("outlook.office365.com", mailAddress, token);
//do what you need here
```

You will need to have [jackson-databind](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind) library with its dependencies in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

More information: [How to access outlook.office365.com IMAP form Java with OAUTH2](https://ralph.blog.imixs.com/2022/10/24/how-to-access-outlook-office365-com-imap-form-java-with-oauth2/)